# Laravel 8, Creating a query builder and adding more queries to it step by step, how can one rollback step by step?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-collection

In laravel 8, i created a simple query builder.

```
$myRestaurants = Restaurant::where('status', 'active');
$myRestaurants->where('id', '>', 3);
$myRestaurants->where('color', 'red');
```

---

the result would be a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder like this:

```
$myRestaurants = Restaurant::where('status', 'active')->where('id', '>', 3)->where('color', 'red');
```

First, Laravel add this queries to $myRestaurants and I am not sure if this behavior is correct. By the way i want to rollback to one step before, like:

```
$myRestaurants = Restaurant::where('status', 'active')->where('id', '>', 3);
```

Comment: Where/how are you automatically adding these conditions to your query?

Comment: The query builder object has public `$bindings` and `$where` properties so you could in theory manipulate those. If you're not careful you might end up completely breaking your query though so probably best to prevent the need before actually adding things to the query

Comment: @Rwd That's the weird part!! I never saved the queries, just call them on the object. I don't know where i have missed but when i add a line like :"$myRestaurants->where('foo', 'bar')", automatically it adds and saves to query builder in the variable ($myRestaurants).

Comment: @apokryfos Aha!. Now I know what is going on. but how can i bypass this?

Comment: What i am trying to do is to filter some models in live-wire. after user deselect some condition i want to go back to previous query.

Comment: This may be an issue with your livewire form not clearing the selections correctly. Check the network tab if the request sent actually has the selections in there or if it correctly clears them

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go back Try `Restaurant::query()`

```php
$myRestaurants = Restaurant::query();
if (true) { // any
    $myRestaurants->where('status', 'active');
}else if(false) {
    $myRestaurants->where('id', ">", 3);
}else if(true) {
    $myRestaurants->where('color', 'red');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's it. I guess 'Restaurant::query()'  resets the query builder, right?. It works!

Comment: @ehsanmohiti yes it's collection all sql statements